# jQuery .remove not working for nested element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to simply remove all nested `li` elements within `ul`, but it is not working. Why won't this snippet work? What am I missing?

html

```
<ul id="myul">
</ul>
<br/>
<button onclick="add();">add</button><br/>
<button onclick="remAll();">remove all</button>
```

js

```
function add()
{
    $('#myul').append('<li>hello world</li>');
}

function remAll()
{
    $('#myul').remove('li');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gPnxY/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do this instead, the selector argument for `remove()` is a filter for the object in question.
In this case the object in question is just the single element with the id `myUl`, therefore not containing any `<li>` elements.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xq4q8/)

```
$('#myul').find('li').remove();
```

or

```
$('#myul li').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation (that's more of what I'm looking for). I don't get it though, because the object in question does contain `li` elements o.O

Comment: It contains them as children, but the function `remove()` is looking at the given object level, not at its children level. An example, let's say you have a class applied to you `<li>`'s. So if you did this, `$('#myul li').remove('.someClass');`, only the `<li>` elements with that class `someClass` would be removed, since they are on the level of the object in question

Comment: Ok, then the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) must be wrong, because it says you can do `$('div').remove('.hello');` and remove all children with `class="hello"`, but it doesn't seem like you can. Thanks.

Comment: Just looked at that example you're talking about, notice the selector, it's just selecting div elements... Has nothing to do with children.

Comment: It's alright, at least you made a valid attempt and used documentation rather that fishing for someone to do all the work for you :)

Answer (score 3):

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/gPnxY/1/)

This is nice:

```
$('#myul').empty();
```

Read more cool stuff: http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Also:

```
$('#myul').find('li').remove();
$('#myul li').remove();
$('#myul').contents().remove();
$('#myul').html('');
```

Comment: @Shredder yup, some are faster some are slower. You can find more info reading the API.

Answer (score 0):

or do:

```
function remAll()
{
    $('#myul').html("");
}
```

**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/Xq4q8/1/

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had ID values generated from content objects, and the values had '.' in them.. e.g.:

```
{ id : 'abc1.ec' }
```

This made my .remove() calls fail on the invalid id string.  Once I figured this out and generated valid ID strings, all worked fine.